# Android and Java: Reduce memory usage on a service loop

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have an Android Service which updates a notification every second using this Thread (comments are not really relevant):

```
thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Preparando la notificación de Swap
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationSwap =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .setContentTitle("Notificator:");
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int notificationSwapId = 1; // TODO: Asignar un ID que no sea "Magic number"

        while (!stop) {
            String swapInfo = null;

            try{ // TODO: free devuelve siempre 4 líneas?
                Process free = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("free");
                BufferedReader freeOut =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(free.getInputStream())));
                free.waitFor();
                freeOut.readLine();
                freeOut.readLine();
                freeOut.readLine();
                swapInfo = freeOut.readLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString()); // TODO: Mejorar esto
            }
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(swapInfo); // TODO: Mejorar esto
            String swapInfo2 = null;
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                scanner.skip("Swap:");
            }
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                /*swapInfo2 = "Total: " + */scanner.nextInt();
            }
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                swapInfo2 = "Usado: " + scanner.nextInt();
            }
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                swapInfo2 += "\nLibre: " + scanner.nextInt();
            }

            // Notificando
            notificationSwap.setContentText(swapInfo2);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationSwapId, notificationSwap.build());

            // Intentando liberar memoria
            //System.gc();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Integer(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("frecuency", "60000"))); // TODO: Mejorar esto
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                Log.d("Notificator (Service)", "Deteniendo el hilo durante la espera"); // TODO: Mejorar esto
                // TODO: ¿Qué pasa si el hilo es interrumpido fuera del try/catch? Si pilla la interrupción no hace falta la variable stop
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that it uses about 20MB of memory but if I uncomment the "//System.gc();" line that number lowers to about 3/4MB, thats A LOT of garbage. But running the whole Garbage Collector every loop does not seem very efficient to me, and CPU usage goes higher.

Thats why I don't like garbage collectors, on a c++ loop just by using auto variables I wouldn't have this problem, but I think this could be better done since I'm not really used neither to Java nor Android.

So, my main question is, how can I lower memory usage in a more eficient way? I also would apreciate better ways to uptate a notification on Android but what I really need is to prevent this kind of code from using so many memory.

**UPDATE:**

Answers are suggesting that I should close the Stream, the Scanner, etc, I'm not really sure whether this is necesary or not (closing the stream and the scanner does not solve the problem) but I think that's not the problem since they are being succesfully deleted anyway.

The problem is that they pile up before being deleted and I want to delete them just before the thread sleeps instead of waiting to the garbage collector, and since that cannot be done in Java as far as I know, I need a more "garbage collector friendly" aproach.

Answer (score 0):

In finally block you can do the following thing

```
 finally {
try {
    freeOut.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You may also add the line `scanner.close()` after `freeOut.close()`.

Main problem here is that you create a new BufferedReader and a new Scanner for each run in the while loop and you never close them, hence the large memory usage.

Comment: Thanks but the objects are being deleted so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I lower memory usage in a more eficient way?

The big thing would be to get rid of all of this process-forking nonsense and replace it with [a simple call to `getMemoryInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryInfo(android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo)). Or, use JNI to call some C APIs to get your memory information. Forking a process every second is exceedingly wasteful on a mobile device. Besides, you have no way of knowing if `free` exists on every device, as on-device command-line binaries are not part of the Android SDK and are not guaranteed to be consistent.

Secondarily, use `StringBuilder` or `String.format()` rather than string concatenation to build up your `Notification` text.

Comment: About getMemoryInfo(): I want to use free, in fact, I want to run a user specified command or script, I'm using free for testing since this is my first Service.

About StringBuilder: I should probably use it. But it's still not solving the main problem: unused objects. I think there should be a way to let the JVM (or Dalvik) know that those objects should be deleted at the end of the loop so it can delete them efficiently...

Comment: @JotaGe: "I want to use free" -- then don't complain about memory usage and don't complain about compatibility. "I think there should be a way to let the JVM (or Dalvik) know that those objects should be deleted at the end of the loop so it can delete them efficiently" -- that is handled for you already. GC is not aggressive until it needs to be (e.g., avoid `OutOfMemoryError`), preferring to wait until more-idle periods. Your a-process-every-second approach will not help here.

Comment: I think you have no right to tell me whether I have to complain about something or not. Here is a more to the point question with no processes involved, anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171211/how-should-i-create-objecs-inside-a-loop-whithout-wasting-memory