# Huge difference on memory ussage between an Android 4 phone and an Android 6 emulator, why?

Tags: android, memory

I'm making and Android App for learning which I test on an Android 4 phone. I launched it by mistake on the emulator (Android 6 x86) and I've noticed a HUGE difference in memory consumption:

[image: Android 4]

[image: Android 6]

Why this difference?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We did not write your app. We do not know what your app does. We do not have a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Use other tools, like heap dumps, to determine what your app is holding onto in the one case that you are not holding onto in the other case. If, later on, you have questions about why some certain piece of code uses a lot more memory on one device than another, we may be in better position to help.

Comment: I think the key is not on my app but on the Android version (Dalvik or ART) or the emulator (x86 vs ARM). Anyway the images show memory usage from a service which run this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143667/android-and-java-reduce-memory-usage-on-a-service-loop
It runs the "free" command and uses it to update a notification.