# How should I create objecs inside a loop whithout wasting memory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have done a test Java program to see how Java behave when "new" is used inside a loop, and my results are really bad. This is the program:

```
package test;

public class Test {
    static int objectCount = 0;

    public static int getObjectCount() {
        return objectCount;
    }

    public Test() {
        objectCount++;
    }

    public void finalize() {
        objectCount--;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxObjects = 0;
        long maxMemory = 0;
        long maxUsedMemory = 0;
        long maxFreeMemory = 0;
        long memory = 0;
        long usedMemory = 0;
        long freeMemory = 0;

        final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Test test = null;
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
            System.gc();
            test = new Test();

            memory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
            freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
            usedMemory = memory - freeMemory;

            if (maxMemory < memory) maxMemory = memory;
            if (maxFreeMemory < freeMemory) maxFreeMemory = freeMemory;
            if (maxUsedMemory < usedMemory) maxUsedMemory = usedMemory;

            if (maxObjects < getObjectCount()) maxObjects = getObjectCount();
        }
        final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        System.out.println(
            "Maximum number of objects simultaneously allocated: "+ maxObjects);
        System.out.println("Max memory: " + maxMemory/1024/1024 + "MB");
        System.out.println("Max used memory: " + maxUsedMemory/1024/1024 +"MB");
        System.out.println("Max free memory: " + maxFreeMemory/1024/1024 +"MB");
        System.out.println("Total Time: " + (t1 - t0)/60 + " secconds");
    }
}
```

Test 1: "System.gc(); and test = new Test();" commented:

```
Maximum number of objects simultaneously allocated: 0
Max memory: 123MB
Max used memory: 0MB
Max free memory: 122MB
Total Time: 17 secconds
```

Test 2: "System.gc();" commented:

```
Maximum number of objects simultaneously allocated: 8196834
Max memory: 696MB
Max used memory: 485MB
Max free memory: 343MB
Total Time: 163 secconds
```

Test 3: nothing commented, total iterations lowered to 10000 (from 10000000):

```
Maximum number of objects simultaneously allocated: 6
Max memory: 123MB
Max used memory: 0MB
Max free memory: 122MB
Total Time: 974 secconds
```

I believe this is awfull, so, how this should be addresed? Is there any way to prevent this?

**UPDATE:**

Test 2 whith -Xmx64M:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at test.Test.main(test.java:31)
```

Same result with 128MB.

Test 2 whith -Xmx256M:

```
(working...) (More than 21 minutes...)
```

Comment: You're wasting your time as a new developer trying to think about memory with Java's automated memory handling and garbage collection. It works just fine, concentrate on writing some interesting software instead and worry more about memory management when/if it becomes relevant.

Comment: What makes you believe this is awful? Based on what research?

Comment: Your tests just show that calling `System.gc()` is slow, that's why you should not call it.

Comment: Hmm. To transform milliseconds into seconds, you normally divide by 1000, not by 60.

Comment: Sorry "Test 2" was wrong. And it was the real problem: "Max memory: 696MB".

@JB Nizet You are right, my mistake.

Comment: Soy my tests show that JVM can take a huge ammount of memory on this code and that calling System.gc is not a good idea to solve it.

Comment: @JotaGe your expectations are wrong. You expect Java to consume as few memory as possible. That's not what Java is optimized to do. Java is optimized to consume the memory you authorized it to consume when it's free, and to release it when it needs to and without interrupting the program for too long. Wouldn't it be stupid to start a JVM with 4GB of heap space and to see it run very slow because it constantly tries keeping the memory usage under 128MB?

Comment: Calling gc() is counterproductive: you ask Java to pause the execution and release memory although plenty of memory is available, and the memory could be released later, after the loop, when the system is idle.

Comment: Well, I understand that garbage collection can be useful but this looks insane to me, if really there is no way to do something like this better then I think Java is seriously flawed.

Comment: @JotaGe you still haven't explained **what** you find awful. What your benchmark is measuring is the time it takes to constantly measure memory, and constantly calling the GC. Nobody constantly calls the GC, because it serves no purpose other than slowing down your program. The VM decides when to run the GC for you, and does it well.

Comment: I find awfull the 696MB of memory usage.

Comment: If you allow Java to consume N MB of memory, it won't consume more than that, and will make sure the code runs as fast as possible. If you remove all the code inside the loop that just measures memory and runs GC constantly, it runs in 11 milliseconds with -Xmx32m. Real programs don't measure memory and run GC constantly.

Answer (score 3):

If you create an Object, then some space is allocated. 
If you create 1000 Objects, then 1000 * x space is allocated.

There is no way to minimize the space of an Object, the solution is to create less Objects or wait for the Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT Taking out all the code which just makes the JITs job harder and running with `verbose:gc -Xmx8m` the following program

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 10000000; i++) {
            Test test = new Test();
        }
        final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total Time: " + (t1 - t0) / 1000.0 + " secconds");
    }
}
```

prints

```
[GC (Allocation Failure)  1535K->424K(7680K), 0.0013697 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  1960K->384K(7680K), 0.0013561 secs]
Total Time: 0.008 secconds
```

Note: this is 100x the iteration count.

> How should I create objecs inside a loop whithout wasting memory?

You are not just wasting memory you are wasting work.  Note: System.gc() is many orders of magnitude more expensive than creating an object.

If you want to optimise you loop, create the object outside the loop.  However, 99% of cases, you don't need to do this and in fact the JIT has Escape Analysis which places the fields of the object on the stack and eliminates the object entirely.

Try running this with `-verbose:gc -Xmx32m` it creates enough objects to fill the whole heap 1000x and yet

```
public class EscapeAnalysisMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2_000_000_000; i++) {
            Integer x = i;
            if (x.hashCode() < 0)
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

prints

```
2000000000
```

i.e. 2 billion `Integer` object but not enough garbage to trip even one collection.  How is that possible? The `Integer` objects were all placed on the stack instead of the heap once the code warmed up so there was no garbage after this (except the last line)

Comment: "If you want to optimise you loop, create the object outside" -> My question is about objects that have to be created *inside* the loop.

Comment: @JotaGe They don't have to be created as often as people think. Even if the object is inside the loop, it doesn't mean it will be created on the heap, it might be on the stack.  If a heap object is created, this doesn't impact performance as much as people often think because it is a very short lived object.  Most of the performance difference in your example is due to other things ou are doing like using `System.gc()` or extending `finalize()`  These have a dramatic impact on performance.

Comment: @JotaGe That is because you are using operations which cannot be optimised away such as overriding `finalize`  Don't do that.

Comment: I'm going to try that but this question comes from this one (no finalize involved): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143667/android-and-java-reduce-memory-usage-on-a-service-loop I've done this thest just to learn how does Java behave in this cases and how calling the garbage collector impacts performance.

Comment: @JotaGe It does impact performance which is why it's generally a bad idea so don't do it unless you have a very good reason. Here is an example of an application where I called System.gc() once per day  because that was the only collection minor or major all day. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html

Comment: @JotaGe I have updated my answer by taking out the real cause of the slow down in your code, still having a object inside the loop.

Comment: You are getting "Allocation Failure", that doesn't mean that is crashing?

Comment: @JotaGe no. it means Java doesn't have enough memory available to allocate the necessary memory, and is thus forced to call the GC to get free memory back.

Comment: @JotaGe it means it had to perform a GC or it would have run out of memory.

Comment: You are right about finalize, that makes my results worst, so my question is "biased" and Java behaves better if I don't overload it. Anyway the related Android question have no finalize() so my question still the same: I want just one object haha. I wish I could just run c/c++ on Android. At least I've learned that finalize can make the GC behave really bad.

Comment: @JotaGe if you want just one object, only create it once outside the loop. If you want to create multiple objects in code but let the JIT work out that really you didn't mean that, you actually wanted one object, you have to use a JIT which does that optimisation.

Comment: Your code is so fast and takes so little memory just because Java is just skipping the for loop. I missed that last time.